# Does the latest version of CiviCRM accommodate PayPal's changes to its dispute tracking?

Tags: paypal

I received this message from PayPal and I am wondering if I need to do anything or if CiviCRM 4.6.4 on Drupal 7 already has it covered.

If not, what do I need to do?

Thanks.

> If you are currently using the Instant Payment Notification (IPN) process or the Case report in your current integration, we want to
>   notify you of a change that may impact your business.
>
> To ensure you don’t experience a disruption of PayPal service, we
>   encourage you to make any applicable changes by July 7, 2015.
>
> What is happening?
>
> We’re enhancing our dispute management system to ensure you receive
>   more detailed and timely information.
>
> The first phase of this enhancement will encompass chargebacks and ACH
>   bank returns. As part of this enhancement, we’ll be updating the
>   format of the Case ID which is the unique identifier we assign to a
>   dispute case.
>
> Why is this happening?
>
> Enhancing our dispute management system will provide more detailed,
>   accurate, and timely information regarding disputes.
>
> What do I need to do?
>
> If you are directly integrating data from the IPN process and/or the
>   Case report into your systems, you will need to ensure that your
>   configuration will accept the format change for the unique dispute
>   identifier as outlined here.
>
> Data passed contains a case_id value. This value will now be formatted
>   in two ways:
>
> Existing format: PP-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX New format: PP-D-XXXX For the new
>   format, XXXX is an integer. The “D” indicates the case is a dispute.
>
> Effective July 15, cases will be identified using either ID format
>   until the transition to the new dispute management system is complete.
>   This is expected to take several years.
>
> As a best practice, merchants are encouraged to integrate flexibly so
>   that any future changes to the unique case identifier can be made
>   without integration changes.
>
> When is this happening?
>
> We will begin generating cases using the new format after July 15. To
>   avoid any disruption to the way you process IPNs or the Case report,
>   please update your integration by this date.
>
> Thanks for your patience as we continue to improve our services.
>
> Your Merchant Services Support Team

Comment: Is anybody else using PayPal and aren't you wondering about this?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I received the same message (I'm using PayPal Standard with CiviCRM on Drupal). I don't believe we need to do anything about it, because CiviCRM doesn't interact with PayPal's dispute process. My experience has always been that if a payment is reversed in PayPal, the reversal is *not* automatically reflected in CiviCRM -- instead, I have to manually edit the CiviCRM contribution record to note that a reversal took place.

As I mentioned, I'm on PayPal Standard. I don't know whether PayPal Pro would be different in this regard, but I doubt it.

Comment: I can confirm in Paypal pro its not any different. Need to edit transaction status manually in CiviCRM.